# Jupiter Ascending alien scene

Tags: jupiter-ascending

In the movie Jupiter Ascending, why do the aliens try to abduct Jupiter's room mate (the chick in the bikini) instead of Jupiter. When they catch Jupiter taking a photo, instead of abducting her, they simply make her forget the incident.

Aren't the minions after Jupiter?

Comment: After reading this question I think there should most definately be a Mila Kunis tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all it wasn't her room mate, it was her employer, Katharine Dunlevy (Vanessa Kirby). Jupiter (Mila Kunis) is a maid in Katharine's home. The reason the Keepers were trying to kidnap Katharine is **because Jupiter had used Katherine's name** at the clinic where Jupiter was going to have her eggs harvested for money. The Keeper's had tracked Katharine thinking it was Jupiter and then tried to capture her, but Jupiter inadvertently foiled the plan when she gave her hiding place away while in the closet.

Comment: Oops yeah, not room mate. The keepers were tracing their target using an Earth name, in spite of all their technology? I thought the fake name for the "egg harvesting" was in a scene that followed the attempted capture event?

Comment: The Keepers found Jupiter through the genetics, but tied it back to the name she used. They followed the name back to the apartment. They thought that Katharine was Jupiter so tried to subdue her first, but that didn't work out so well :D When they realized it was the wrong person, they waited for Jupiter to come into the clinic. When she did, they tried to kill her, but Caine saves the day.